# How to create wiremock stubs in NestJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, stub, wiremock

I have a requirement to create Wiremock stubs in NestJS.
As per the firm policy, I can only use Wiremock NPM as mentioned here: [Wiremock NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wiremock)

However, there is a limited documentation available so trying to figure out the basics here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.